# Extract columns from Excel and turn them into rows in a matrix

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

I have collected data from ten test machines. Each collected data is a 2879x35 matrix. The 35 columns represent variables. The tricky part is that I have to perform a statistical analysis and I need these variables to be in rows. The even trickier part is that the variables from each machine need to stacked on top of one another with the second, third etc. columns of variables next to each other. E.g:

```
machine_1 = 1 2 3 
            4 5 6
            7 8 9

machine_2 = a b c
            d e f
            g h i
```

What I need:

```
Fat_matrix = 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
             a d g b e h c f i
```

I have these data in Excel with each column labeled, and I'm working with MATLAB.

Comment: If you want to convert a matrix on the form `mat = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]` to the form `[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]` all you have to do is `mat(:)'`.

Comment: How are you reading the data into Matlab? How is it organized in Excel? Is each machine a separate worksheet or a separate workbook...?

Comment: I use xlsread. In excel it is organized as such:

Machine         variable1   variable2  variable3...etc
1                          x1             x2            x3 

Each machine is on a separate workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic answer in relation to you question is

```
machine_1 = [1 2 3 
            4 5 6
            7 8 9]
machine_2 = [10 11 12
            13 14 15
            16 17 18]        

mach1_new= reshape(machine_1,1,9)       
mach2_new= reshape(machine_2,1,9)
[mach1_new' mach2_new']'
```

follwing beakers comment:

```
[mach1_new; mach2_new]
```

provides the same result.

if you want to do it for more, if it contains strings and characters as you show above, or if you want to read it in automatically its more difficult and we would need more information...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be trying it today. And to answer your question, no, there are no strings or characters, I just used them for illustration.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing all those transposes in the last line. Why not `[mach1_new ; mach2_new]`? The semicolon will put `mach2_new` on the next row.